# Matching and aggregating data between two overlapped layers using QGIS

Tags: qgis, field-calculator, geometry

I'd like to know how a vector layer can take and aggregate attributes of a field, of another vector layer which is overlapped.

For example, a layer T1 has not overlapped records while on the contrary the layer T2 could have overlapped records. I should have a "NEW" field in T1 with the data of T2, separated with ';' every time T2 records overlaps on T1.

[image]

[image]

[image]

How do I automate this process using QGIS?

Comment: Online Tutorial: https://spatialthoughts.com/2019/04/12/summary-aggregation-qgis/